# How do you open a link to a secure website with VBA in Excel?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web

I am trying to create a macro to open several links from a secured website (meaning login and password are required when normally accessing the site). Each link would normally export a report to the download folder if already logged into the site, but the goal is to have other users with their own website login credentials to be able to utilize the macro. I'd have other vba coding to utilize the downloads and update a report in excel. This basically consolidates information from the website into one page, as opposed to navigating through several webpages for information. Also, it appears the links to the downloads contains an "access token", so I'm assuming I can't use a static link in the macro. Any thoughts or direction appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, I think Excel VBA is a horrible choice for what you want to do and  you would be much better off using .NET. I highly recommend a different approach. First, I would do some research to make sure that the company does not already offer an API. If one exists, that will make life much easier. If not, well get ready to roll up your sleeves because you have some very frustrating code to write. About the easiest way to achieve your goal would have to be using a web browser control in a form to let the user log in and navigate to the reports. If you study how the links are constructed, then you could possibly write a procedure to detect those links and use said control to initiate downloads. At least that takes much of the manual work away from the end-user, but again, it is not ideal and you really should not use Excel for that.

One thing I would also like to mention- I have written an application before that did almost exactly the same as what you have in mind. It was a lot of work to squash every possible bug and I had to cross my fingers that the site it accessed did not go through a sudden re-design because that would break it. Somehow by a stroke of good luck it kept working for three years. Eventually though, the inevitable happened and the tool was rendered useless. You might want to ask yourself if something like this is truly worth the effort involved.